# an + Dativ or an + Akkusativ

Tags: preposition, article

In A1, we have learned that after *an*, we should use the article of the next word in *Dativ*, if we want to mean on something. For example: *an der Wand*. I have also sometimes encountered a sentence like this:

*Hängen Sie bitte das Bild an die Wand.*

What's the difference between these two?

**Edit**

Another example, which I cannot understand what their differences are, is:

*Schreiben Sie die Sätze ins Heft.*

*Schreiben Sie die Sätze im Heft.*

Comment: @DavidVogt I guess so! Thanks.

Comment: I picked the first similar question I could find. If you look for [two-way prepositions](https://german.stackexchange.com/search?q=two-way+prepositions), there should be loads of similar questions, hopefully some of them with helpful answers.

Comment: @DavidVogt Thank you very much for your helpful comment.